# help me out making my transition from iphone please

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-galaxy-note

I am used to doing a long-press-on-the-home-button to trigger the voice- search. That's a bad iphone habit. Here with Android, it is always switching to the currently-running-apps screen.

I tried so many ways ( including the home2 share app) but I could not figure it out.

Could you tell me an easy way to configure note 3 ( or s4) hardware buttons so that I can program them to do certain things upon long press, double click, even triple click etc...  What's the best app for that?

And secondly (and more practically speaking), please tell me how I can configure that a long press on the home button puts the phone into the listening mode?

Thank you...

Comment: Joe, just splitting some hairs: it's not the "currently running apps", but the "recently used apps" (which are not necessarily running in background, though some certainly still do). As for your button issue: have you tried long-pressing the search button (if there is any)? That's what I've heard did it on other devices, if I remember correctly.

Comment: If you have the Note3 or S4, that might be getting KitKat soon, so you can activate listening simply by saying "Ok, Google"

Comment: Izzy, thank you for pointing out. That recently used apps thing... That I did not know. thx for that. As to the long press on the search button issue.. well, that does the multi-window icon for me. On a different issue: Is there a way to configure the power button on the site to do literally well, "nothing"? :) It gets in the way many times... and I accidentally close the  phone..  For turning on or off of the phone, I'd rather do a double click.. that would have been so much better for me... Are there apps that lets you do these things without rooting the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put Android into "listening mode", do your Long press, then click on the Google logo at the bottom of the screen. That's Google Now, your Siri counterpart.

For Samsung devices with S-Voice, double-pressing quickly on the Home button will trigger S-Voice.

Comment: any more app/setting recommendations for other hardware button configurations for their long presses or double/triple click stuff... I'd appreciate it if you know of a good app for this.